# How set marker on click when map load - Mapbox GLJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I've made a MapBox for get Current Coordinate for Gmaps :

```
mapboxgl.accessToken ='pk.eyJ1IjoibW5hdWZhbGF6a2lhIiwiYSI6ImNrcWV4MzN0ZDA2NjQyd2xrazhhbG96eHMifQ.3R_B2O8m_CQ_tERmmji8mA';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: [107.138013,-6.814071],
        zoom: 13,
    });
    
    // Add the control to the map.
    var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
        marker: false,
        mapboxgl: mapboxgl
    });

document.getElementById('geocoder').appendChild(geocoder.onAdd(map));


geocoder.on('result', function(r) {
    document.getElementById("maps").value = r.result.center;
    var reverse = document.getElementById("maps").value;
    reverse = reverse.split(",");
    var latitude = reverse[1];
    var longitude = reverse[0];
    document.getElementById("maps").value = latitude + "," + longitude;
  
    var marker1 = new mapboxgl.Marker({ draggable: false, color: "blue" })
    .setLngLat(r.result.center)
    .addTo(map);
    map.flyTo({
    center: r.result.center,
    zoom:15,
    speed:5,
    });
    map.on('click', function(e) {
            var coordinates = e.lngLat;
        var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(coordinates)
        .setHTML('MapBox Coordinate<br/>' + coordinates)
        .addTo(map);
        marker1.setLngLat(coordinates)
        marker1.setPopup(popup)
        map.flyTo({
        center: coordinates,
        zoom:15,
        speed:5,
        });
      document.getElementById("maps").value = coordinates;
      var lokasi = $('#maps').val().replace(/[^0-9,.-]/ig, "");
      $('#maps').val(lokasi);
      var reverse = document.getElementById("maps").value;
      reverse = reverse.split(",");
      var latitude = reverse[1];
      var longitude = reverse[0];
      document.getElementById("maps").value = latitude + "," + longitude;
          });
});

$('#modalrubahlokasi').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    map.resize();
});

document.querySelector('.mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder input').placeholder = "Search Location Here";
```

Here's codepen links :
https://codepen.io/mnaufalazkia/pen/wvdwmoY

But I can't set marker when i click the map before i've search the location first.

But i've tried *map.on('load' function* **and add** *map.on('click'* for map load function for set marker, but not working properly. but when i search the location first, and click the maps, the marker working properly.

Someone can help me to add marker when i click the map, just like when i search the location first, but of course remove the previous marker. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of the following suggestions came from retooling of these resources:

- https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/9209
- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#marker#remove
- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup/
- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#marker-example
- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-click/

You can achieve setting a marker when you click the map before searching the location by adding markers to the map independently of the `geocoder` after the map has been initialized by:

```js
map.on('click', function add_marker (event) {
  var coordinates = event.lngLat;
  console.log('Lng:', coordinates.lng, 'Lat:', coordinates.lat), 'id', event.id;
  marker.setLngLat(coordinates).addTo(map);
// Ensure that if the map is zoomed out such that multiple
// copies of the feature are visible, the popup appears
// over the copy being pointed to.
while (Math.abs(event.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
coordinates[0] += event.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
}
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 35 })
.setLngLat(coordinates)
        .setHTML('MapBox Coordinate<br/>' + coordinates)
        .addTo(map)
})
```

Then you can handle your popups within your `geocoder` to close out when you click away. There isn't a need to call a `map.on('click')` again here.

```js
geocoder.on('result', function(r) {
    document.getElementById("maps").value = r.result.center;
    var reverse = document.getElementById("maps").value;
   
    var latitude = reverse[1];
    var longitude = reverse[0];
    document.getElementById("maps").value = latitude + "," + longitude;
  
    var marker1 = new mapboxgl.Marker({ draggable: false, color: "blue"})
    .setLngLat(r.result.center)
    .addTo(map);
    map.flyTo({
    center: r.result.center,
    zoom:15,
    speed:5,
    })
    
    new mapboxgl.Popup({offset: 35, closeOnClick: true})
        .setLngLat(r.result.center)
        .setHTML('MapBox Coordinate<br/>' + r.result.center)
        .addTo(map);
    map.on('click', function(){
        marker1.remove();
    })
});
```

Here is a working example in a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jameslcarpino/gchsvoxL/1/

Comment: Thank you, i've follow suggestions from any example but i'm still confuse, because i'm new in coding. but i'm helped from your jsfiddle, thank you.